# C# User Control Leave Event

Tags: c#, controls

I am very new with the C# UserControl. I have problems with the event Leave. This is my situation:  I would like to go from `usercontrolA` to `userControlB`. Before going to `userControlB`, `usercontrolA_Leave` event is called.

```
private void usercontrolA_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("you are leaving.....");
}
```

After `MessageBox` is shown, the program will not proceed to my `userControlB`. HOWEVER when there is no `MessageBox` in the code, the program can proceed to `userControlB`.

```
private void usercontrolA_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e){//anything but MessageBox}
```

In my case, I need `MessageBox`.

I need `MessageBox`(or other thing) for me to decide whether staying or leaving.. .

[msdn Control.Leave Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I heard about setting `set focus`or `lost focus`. Is that possible to use this?

I hope you guys could understand what I have written. Thank you in advance.. :)

Comment: When you say "go from usercontrolA to userControlB" what do you mean? Like "move the mouse from A to B" or move the focus, or what?

Comment: What is the event you are using on the `userControlB`? The Enter event? Or the leave one?

Comment: @jwatts1980 yes..move the mouse from A n click on B..

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm so sorry that I describe it too abstract.. Actually B is a button in MainForm.. Button Click..

Comment: Using MessageBox in the Leave event is a very drastic mistake.  Leave is triggered when the focus changes.  But MessageBox steals the focus away.   What has the focus when you close it?  Not what you think, don't do it.

Comment: @HansPassant thank you.. but I need something to notify me, not textbox but something(example like message box) for me to decide "staying or leaving" ..

Comment: Use the Validating event, set e.Cancel to *true* when you are unhappy about something.  Use ErrorProvider to make notification subtle, message boxes suck.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to preserve mouse movements once a `MessageBox` is created. This is a modal box that comes up on top of the existing window and takes the focus away from the current form and interrupts the mouse.

Consider an option that does not interrupt the mouse, such as writing out to a textbox. Create a `TextBox` will the multi-line and scrollbar options enabled. Then write to it.

```
private void usercontrolA_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Append("you are leaving A...\r\n");
}

private void usercontrolB_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Append("you are entering B...\r\n");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me that it is unable to preserve mouse movements once a 'MessageBox' is created. Actually , my idea is after dealing with the MessageBox, I can directly proceed to my B_Click


    private void usercontrolA_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("SaveChanges?","Error",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    }

Comment: I think the problem might be that your mouse movement into B has triggered the message box so when you think you are clicking on B you have in fact done nothing. I am not 100% sure on that and have no way to check it out at the moment but initially that would be my guess.

Comment: @Keithin8a thanks for responding... 
the mouse CLICK into B has triggered the message box from my userControlA. Mouse move to B will not trigger the message box A.